# It's showing category first and second both in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created slider category and about category and then try to put slider category in slider carousel slider but, it's showing(sliding) both category's image. I want to slide only slider category's image what should i do my code is here

```
<div class="slider">
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php
            // Example argument that defines eight posts per page.
                $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 6 ,
                    'category' => 8, 
                    'post_type'        => 'post',
                    );

                // Variable to call WP_Query.
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                    {
                      $count1++;
            ?>
             <?php
                  if($count1===1)
                  {

              ?>
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            </div>
                <?php }
                    else{
                ?>
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
            </div>

            <?php
                }
                }
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>

          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What you should do is [Read the Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) and see that `category` is _not_ a valid argument in your WP_Query

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my time